# delay after requestAuthorizationToShareTypes

Tags: ios8, hkhealthstore

I am setting up an iOS 8 app to request Heath Kit Store authorization to share types. The request Read/Write screen shows fine and on selecting Done, I see the completion callback immediately after. In this callback, I am pushing a new view controller. I set a breakpoint for the code that is programmatically pushing the next view controller and this is called immediately, but the transition doesn't occur until about 10 seconds later.

Some code:

```
@IBAction func enable(sender: AnyObject) {
    let hkManager = HealthKitManager()
    hkManager.setupHealthStoreIfPossible { (success, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            println("error = \(error)")
        } else {
            println("enable HK success = \(success)")
            self.nextStep()
        }
    }
}

func nextStep() {
        self.nav!.pushViewController(nextController, animated: true)
}


class HealthKitManager: NSObject {

    let healthStore: HKHealthStore!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    }

    class func isHealthKitAvailable() -> Bool {
        return HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()
    }

    func setupHealthStoreIfPossible(completion: ((Bool, NSError!) -> Void)!) {
        if HealthKitManager.isHealthKitAvailable()
        {
            healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(dataTypesToWrite(), readTypes: dataTypesToRead(), completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                completion(success, error)
            })
        }
    }

    func dataTypesToWrite() -> NSSet {
        let runningType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)
        let stepType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)

        return NSSet(objects: runningType, stepType)
    }

    func dataTypesToRead() -> NSSet {
        let runningType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)
        let stepType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
        let climbedType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed)

        return NSSet(objects: runningType, stepType, climbedType)
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what is causing the time delay for the transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the completion block is returned in the background queue. I just put the transition call back onto the main queue as follows:

```
hkManager.setupHealthStoreIfPossible { (success, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            println("error = \(error)")
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                println("enable HK success = \(success)")
                self.nextStep()
            });

        }
    }
}
```